# What could be the cause of a button's failure on my laptop's keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard, hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop

Basically, it is the v button, I do not know what happened to it, it works sometimes and others it doesn't. Sometimes a simple restart to my laptop fixes it and then after a while when my computer is still on it stops working, and then again it does after like 20 mins or so. Sometimes when it doesn't register, I click it a few times and it works, it stays working for some time and again it gets disabled, I am not sure if this is a software issue ( Drivers for example ) or hardware, but I am sure that it is not dust or debris inside the key itself ( Not sure about the keyboard from the inside or the motherboard) as I have cleaned it numerous times using compressed air.

Comment: Most of the time failing single keys are a hardware problem.

Comment: So any suggestions on how to solve it? Maybe replace the keyboard or something?

Comment: (1) Clean keyboard (e.g. with compressed air), (2) If you are mechanically skilled: open up keyboard, look at specific key, look at possibly broken traces, (3) replace keyboard